# Java XPath expression to get the previous sibling

Tags: java, dom, xpath

```
Given the below XML
</parties>
    <party>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <typeCode>D</typeCode>
        <typeDesc>Defendant</typeDesc>
        <info></info>
        <otherData>
           <partySeqNum>2</partySeqNum>
           <partyTitle></partyTitle>
           <partyAddDate></partyAddDate>
           <terminateDate></terminateDate>
           <indexPartyName>Tom</indexPartyName>
        </otherData>
    </party>
    <party>
        <name>Jim</name>
        <typeCode>DE</typeCode>
        <typeDesc>Defendant</typeDesc>
        <info></info>
        <otherData>
           <partySeqNum>2</partySeqNum>
           <partyTitle></partyTitle>
           <partyAddDate></partyAddDate>
           <terminateDate></terminateDate>
           <indexPartyName>Tom</indexPartyName>
        </otherData>
    </party>
</parties>
```

I have an util that return me the xpath : `/parties/party(1)/typeDesc`

Is there a way i can get an expression to return me the previous sibling of `/parties/party(1)/typeDesc`, which will be `/parties/party(1)/typeCode`.

I general, whatever xpath expression i get, i need to gets its previous sibling.

```
xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocumentOrg, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String expression = "/parties/party[1]/typeDesc";
    String precedingSiblingExpression = expression + "/preceding-sibling::*[1]";
    Node result = (Node) xpath.compile(precedingSiblingExpression).evaluate(source, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what i was looking for.